# Converting a number into an array of digits

Tags: arrays, loops, integer, modulo

I'm having a little problem converting a number into an array of digits.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[11];
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        a[i] =  number%10;
        number = number/10;
    }
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        cout << a[i];
cout << endl;
}
```

Instead of getting the number I entered, I get some random digits. This problem doesn't occur when the the number I enter is less or equal than 9 digits.

Comment: Have you thought about ints max size?

Comment: You're right, int size was not enough, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to init the array(is a good practice) doing somethinglike:

```
int a[11] = {-1};
```

and if you add a newline char after printing every element of the array then it will become meaningful and easier to read...

your code is working as expected actually

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a[11] = {-1};
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
    {

        a[i] = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        cout <<"@[" <<i<<"]: "<< a[i] <<endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

for an input like **432**

you get the output:

[image]

Comment: I know, but the problem occurred with number greater than 9 digits - now I know the int "number" size was too small. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: Hi @Paweł... thanks for the feedback... lt me check that please!